# c# Не обрабатывается событие MouseUp

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме расположена панель. При удерживании левой кнопки мыши на этой панели происходит перемещение формы и изменение ее прозрачности. При отпускании левой кнопки прозрачность возвращается на 100%. 
Проблема в том, что событие panel1_MouseUp не срабатывает на левой клавише. На правой всё работает отлично. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Opacity = 0.5;
        ReleaseCapture();
        PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Opacity = 1;
    }
```

Собственно полный способ перемещения (скопированный с просторов интернета):

```
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint      WParam, uint LParam);
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static bool ReleaseCapture();

    const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const uint DOMOVE = 0xF012;
    const uint DOSIZE = 0xF008;
```

Comment: а не `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            //do something here
        }
        else
        {
            //do something here for left or middle click
        }` где `MouseButtons` перечисление https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx  .. кстати, для `MouseDown` тоже если надо различать нажатие - надо примерно также писать

Comment: без `PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);` все работает отлично на обеих кнопках, что-то не так с функцией перемещения

Comment: а чем не угодил обычный вариант перемещения формы без обращений к WinApi напрямую?

Comment: @rdorn: Думаю, ТС и не пробовал, он же говорит, что нашёл код в инете, и теперь хочет найти в инете кого-нибудь, кто заставил бы этот код работать.

Comment: @VladD похоже на то. Но мне больше интересно что на самом деле происходит при этом проблемном вызове. в MSDN только общие слова, так что я только в общих чертах понял в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос в описании `ReleaseCapture();` [**читать**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646261(v=vs.85).aspx). Закоментируйте в вашем коде `PostMessage` и посмотрите что произойдет, когда после клика на форме, вы отпустите клавишу за пределами формы. Событие отжатия кнопки мыши за пределами формы не попадет в вашу форму. Тоже происходит и при перемещении.

На мой взгляд, в .NET не стоит дергать WinAPI без острой необходимости. Для перемещения формы можете заменить обращение к WinAPI например так:

```
private Point startMovePos;//точка относительно которой будем перемещать форму
private bool isMouseDown = false;//флаг нажатия кнопки мыши

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Opacity = 0.5;
    startMovePos = e.Location;//фиксируем положение мыши в момент нажатия клавиши
    isMouseDown = true;
    //ReleaseCapture();
    //PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Opacity = 1;
    isMouseDown = false;
}

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Двигаем форму относительно точки полученной при нажатии кнопки мыши
    //Пересчет координат мыши не требуется, т.к. нам нужно только относительное смещение.
    if(isMouseDown)
    {
        var dx = e.X - startMovePos.X;
        var dy = e.Y - startMovePos.Y;
        Location = new Point(Location.X+dx, Location.Y+dy);
    }
}
```

Кода немного больше, но вы полностью управляете им и можете самостоятельно выбрать какой клавишей таскать форму, а какой выполнять другие действия. Как проверить какая клавиша нажата уже написали в соседнем ответе.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение!

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое перечисление, как [MouseButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx), которое задает константы, определяющие, какая кнопка мыши была нажата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В событии можно определить, а какая конкретно клавиша всё-таки была нажата и исходя из этого что-то делать.

Можно через `if`. Если все нажатия отслеживаются, можно через `switch` или еще различными способами.

Например

```
private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {   
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
     //do something here
   } else { //left or middle click
     //do something here
   }
}
```

или

```
private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {   
    switch (e.Button) {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
       // Left click
       break;

       case MouseButtons.Right:
       // Right click
       break;
       ...
   }
}
```

и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ. Но!
Проблема то в другом. Цитата "Проблема в том, что событие panel1_MouseUp не срабатывает". Именно не обрабатывается событие. Я уже пробовал делать проверку клавиши. 
Как правильно подметил в комментариях пользователь [rdorn](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198316/rdorn), если убрать 
    PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
то событие будет нормально обрабатываться. Именно для пояснения ситуации я опубликовал полный код реализации перемещения формы.